# The target entry-point "@angular/fire/database" has missing dependencies: - @angular/core

Tags: angular, npm, angularfire

I'm stuck with this error after running `ionic serve` in my project folder, even though I have a version of @angular/core installed in my local node_modules. What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it? There error seemingly came from nowhere since it wasn't thrown until I started working with mapbox, shown below. Here is my ***package.json***:

```
{
  "name": "outsourcd",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.19.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.12.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1000.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.11.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

When I run `ng version` this is my output:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 14.8.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... cli, common, core
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.1000.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core                10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics          9.1.12
@angular/compiler                   10.0.14
@angular/compiler-cli               10.0.14
@angular/fire                       6.0.2
@angular/forms                      10.0.14
@angular/language-service           10.0.14
@angular/platform-browser           10.0.14
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   10.0.14
@angular/router                     10.0.14
@ngtools/webpack                    10.0.8
@schematics/angular                 9.1.12
@schematics/update                  0.901.12
rxjs                                6.6.2
typescript                          3.9.7
webpack                             4.43.0
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- uninstalling and reinstalling @angular/fire
- removing node_modules and running `npm install`
- unlinking @angular/fire
  (however, when I try to uninstall/unlink @angular/fire, I still get an error on missing dependencies from @angular/fire/database when running `ionic serve`)